# Magento index page is too slow while all inner pages are working quickly

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9, magento-1.9.1

I am working on a site where the index page is loading too slow while all the inner pages are working quickly.

[**This**](http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/#!/belRjl/http://toolsandgear.com.au/index.php/) is showing that the "Wait" time is the highest but I think if anything is wrong on the website then how can it be possible that the inner pages work fine? I am using **Magento 1.9**. I already tried all the ways available on Google to boost up the speed of website.

Comment: this does not look code related to me.  it looks like a server issue.   can you describe your hosting environment?   there's a long wait for "TTFB" on this site,  so I'm guessing something's up with your server.

Answer (score 1):

```
curl -o /dev/null -w "Connect: %{time_connect} TTFB: %{time_starttransfer} Total time: %{time_total} \n" http://toolsandgear.com.au

Connect: 0,179 TTFB: 9,287 Total time: 10,188
```

TTFB is more than 9 sec. It's too long - this mean what you have TTFB (Time To First Byte) issue. In most cases TTFB issue belongs to wrong server settings or to overhead during page generation on server side (too many hard sql-queries on page, etc). More detailed:

```
time curl http://toolsandgear.com.au/ -v --output /dev/null

 % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0*   Trying 108.167.181.160...
* Connected to toolsandgear.com.au (108.167.181.160) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: toolsandgear.com.au
> User-Agent: curl/7.42.0
> Accept: */*
> 
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:09 --:--:--     0< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: nginx/1.6.2
< Date: Thu, 30 Apr 2015 16:19:47 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Connection: keep-alive
< Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
< Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
< Pragma: no-cache
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
< Set-Cookie: frontend=b024b8022ebb90a78afff9ccdb472764; expires=Thu, 30-Apr-2015 17:19:37 GMT; path=/; domain=toolsandgear.com.au; HttpOnly
< Set-Cookie: sns_furni_tpl=sns_furni; expires=Tue, 19-Apr-2016 16:19:37 GMT; path=/
< 
{ [9577 bytes data]
100  217k    0  217k    0     0  20380      0 --:--:--  0:00:10 --:--:-- 60239
* Connection #0 to host toolsandgear.com.au left intact

real    0m10.917s
user    0m0.017s
sys     0m0.007s
```

Common Nginx settings seems to be fine. Try to optimize Nginx configuration (cache/gzip compression) and profile Magento home page for catching long SQL queries, cycles in cycles, etc.